# Getting SQL Error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using Asp.Net (C#) I'm submitting the following value to a field in the DB:

```
//Adding to parameters (for stored proc)
command.Parameters.Add( "MyField", SqlDbType.Bit, 1 ).Value = "1";
```

How do I fix this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `SqlDbType.Bit` is:

> An unsigned numeric value that can be 0, 1, or null.

So, try:

```
command.Parameters.Add( "MyField", SqlDbType.Bit, 1 ).Value = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

`cmd.Parameters.Add("MyField", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true;`